# Drupal: what happen when I change the server root folder?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've drupal installed in www.mywebsite.com/drupal

I'm now ready to change the root directory of the website to drupal/ in order to make it available as 'www.mywebsite.com'.

However I was wondering if all the files and images uploaded with CCK content fields won't have broken links.

I guess Drupal uses `$site_url` to do this, so I'm not going to have issues.. but I just want to be sure :)

thanks

Comment: Do you really need to root directory to make the site available as www.mywebsite.com?

Comment: do I not need it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Eaton says, you won't have any trouble with stuf uploaded through CCK fields, however, if you have stuf like images in the body of content, these will probably be broken when you change the root folder of drupal.

If you find such cases, I suggest you do a "search and replace" for strings that go like "/drupal/*" and the like, and change them for /, through out the db.

Answer (score 0):

You'll only be tripped up if you've left hard-coded URLs somewhere in your site. Those can sneak into strange places -- for example, if someone has posted content with hard-coded links.

As you suspect, though, Drupal itself is fine with the directory being shifted around.